Forecasting for Multivariate Time Series on Multiple Subject
Let's imagine I have time series data for 50 users and 20 features per user: User1_ts(F1,...F20), User2_ts(F1,...F20), ...User50_ts(F1,...F20). F20 is my target variable, and the goal is to apply to apply "multi-VAR-like" model for forecasting F20. At the moment, I am applying a VAR model to each Useri_ts(F1,...F20), ending to have 50 VAR models (one for each user).
Q: How to build the "training set" in order to apply "multi-VAR-like" analysis? Any reference to python?
If I was using an DL/LSTM approach, I can build the three dimensional tensor. But it is not the case, as I am in favor of applying a VAR-like model for better understanding the relationships between the predictors.
I have been trying to find a way how to apply a single VAR model over multiple subjects, and I come across the following paper https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35060013/
which describes the "multi-VAR problem" as a theoretical way to systematically apply VAR over different subjects. It seems to be the SOTA in this domain and is still under development. I could only find the implementation in R https://github.com/zackfisher/multivar
but not in Python. Any help on what python implement as library or model?

Can you provide more information on what exactly User1_ts(F1,...,F20) means? Are F1-F20 supposed to be 20 time series? Furthermore, what do you mean with a multi-VAR-like analysis? Are you interested in panel VARs?

@Louki, I have edited the post based on an earlier interaction with Carlo. I hope the setup is clearer now.
